# In Python, why is a bare function object valid code?

Tags: python

Why is the following valid?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def spam():
   pass

spam
```

I understand that functions are objects but I think code such as the above is never useful and always the result of a mistake. Why doesn't it result in an error on the line referencing the spam function object?

Comment: Why should it result in an error? It is an absolutely valid Python syntax.

Comment: It is useful while designing.

Comment: How is the language supposed to know what is "useful" and what isn't?

Comment: I really don't understand the down/close votes here, this seems like a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: No, it is not reasonable without reading the documentation which perfectly explains, what is `pass` and where it is used.

Comment: @BasicWolf `pass` is a statement and reserved word, so it's not relevant.

Comment: @BasicWolf The question isn't about the usage of `pass`, it is about having `spam` on a line all by itself (as opposed to calling it using `spam()`).

Answer (score 7):

Every expression is a valid statement. Using a local variable (no matter what it refers to) is a valid expression. Due to late binding and dynamicness, you can't detect at compile time whether it refers to a function or something else (though in this case you don't need to know that, as just referencing a local never does anything). A runtime check would be quite expensive for no gain.

That leaves prohibiting statements of the form `<local variable>;`. Prohibiting this case specifically is inconsistent, takes extra work, and does not help much IMHO. I don't see a technical reason it couldn't be done, so it probably boils down to the BDFL not wanting a special case for this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `spam` and `spam()` are of course fundamentally different statements. This becomes clear if you look at the difference between `a = spam` and `a = spam()`. The first stores the function in variable `a`, the second stores the return value of one call of the function that takes place at that very moment. Both are useful but different operations.

Just mentioning the function like in `spam` is not doing something useful, no. But just stating values is not forbidden in python. Following your argumentation, the single statement `4` should be illegal, too, as would be any litteral value. This would actually forbit using pydoc strings anywhere, since they are just mentions of a otherwise useless value (from a executional point of view).

So I think it could have been forbidden to use such bare values, but it wasn't, and nowadays it even has usage.

Comment: You said what I was trying to say much better. I deleted mine and +1 for yours!

Comment: You could special case for docstrings. I believe what OP is getting at is that the added value of having Python catch the "forgot to call  the function" error is worth the (extremely slight) cost of handling bare expressions.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Yes, you could, and it would help you detect many errors in your code, I guess. Still, it would somehow not feel very pythonic to me, don't know why. And it would not really fit in well into interactive python prompt, where every "mentioned" value is displayed to you (I often type something like `spam` there, to find out, what things are and where they are from. Not sure, if that is a good reason to have it in interpreted/compiled language, though.

Comment: Yeah, the REPL usage is important. Still, that's already a special case (outputting instead of discarding the result), so...

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, referencing a bare expression can have side effects. The code:

```
class Nugget(object):
    @property
    def spam(self):
        print "does merely referencing a property invoke it?"

n = Nugget()
n.spam           # no explicit invocation
```

Does in fact print the message. To give you an error in your example case would break the generality of this case.

Comment: Getting an attribute and just referencing a bare name are quite different things. The former can (as you show) execute arbitrary code, while the latter cannot (at least for locals, and I believe you need deep, implementation-specific magic for globals).

Comment: Hm, I think you're right, though my mental model is pretty broken here. A property at module scope instead of inside a class does nothing, which I'm not sure how I feel about.

Comment: I think your example is not really a mentioning of a function but (to the outside) the mentioning of a a variable. Hence it quite clearly shows, what an impact changing such basic bahaviour in python whoud have, since internally some things are not quite what they look like.